# how to use amchart in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amcharts, nuxt.js

I want to use amcharts in nuxt.

In svg-map.vue component, I have added below code

```
head() {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: 'js/amcharts/core.js' }
      ]
    };
  },
```

but this gives me following error

> Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
>
> (intermediate value)(intermediate value).push is not a function

When I saw this to chrome, it shows error on push function in below line

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["pages_coutrypedia"],{
```

does anyone know what cause this error?

Answer (score 2):

use nuxt custom plugin , create a file plugins/amcharts.js

```
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
import am4themes_dark from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/dark";
import Vue from "vue";
Vue.prototype.$am4core = () => {
 return {
  am4core,
  am4charts,
  am4themes_animated,
  am4themes_dark
 }
}
```

then add to nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    {
        src: '~/plugins/amCharts.js',
        ssr: false
    }
],
```

in component .vue file

```
mounted() {
 let {am4core, am4charts, am4themes_animated, am4themes_dark} = this.$am4core();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found solution.

After searching a lot I found that nuxt and amcharts both were using different versions of webpack. Previous version of webpack uses webpackJsonp as function and newer version uses webpackJsonp as an array.

First amcharts js were loading so it declares webpackJsonp as a function. Then nuxt uses it and calls push function to it. Which was giving an error.

So I gave custom jsonpFunction string in webpack config in nuxt.config file as below

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  config.output = {
    jsonpFunction: 'webpackLoad'
  };
}
```

But this also doesnt solves my error, when I run nuxt it doesn't load localhost, it was just showing waiting.

Then I have just downloaded amchart libraries and replaced webpackJsonp with webpackLoad in all places. And that solves my problem.

**Edit:**

I have downloaded modules using npm as mentioned [here](https://www.amcharts.com/download/)

Then used below code

```
if (process.browser) {
  var am4core = require('@amcharts/amcharts4/core'),
    am4maps = require('@amcharts/amcharts4/maps'),
    am4geodata_world = require('@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldIndiaHigh').default,
    am4themes_animated = require('@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated').default;
}
```

Then in mounted

```
mounted() {
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

    var chart = am4core.create(this.$el, am4maps.MapChart);
}
```